# Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? Insert '!'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

When i set background image for view controller i'm getting some error like this....

```
Error:    Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? Insert '!'
```

My code is...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image.png"))

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix :

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
if image != nil {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:image)
}
```

Because `UIImage(named: "image.png")`, this will return optional image object. ie if image not avail, it will return nil.

[From Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init)

**Return Value**

> The image object for the specified file, or nil if the method could
>   not find the specified image.

Comment: Yes, it's working...Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. If your question gets resolved, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: In this case `!` can be safely used because you should make sure the image is present in your assets. It should be used without extension though `UIImage(named: "image")`.

Comment: Yes. @Sulthan you're right. If the screen is least open or tester missed that page, this code will get crash on App store. If you write it, everyone can identify the empty space on the specified imageView.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image.png"))` with `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "image.png")!)`

Comment: It's getting this error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @iOS, not possible, I have tested this and it works fine and than I post answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right ...It's crashed initially, because image not available with that name (image.png). Now problem solved thank you very much...